# Why does Dreamweaver add an icon to my "a" element?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I just found that, in Adobe Dreamweaver CS3, this code segment seems fine in the design view,

```
<a href="#">Test Anchor</a>
```

but if I add an "id" attribute to this "a" tag, like this,

```
<a id="test" href="#">Test Anchor</a>
```

there would be an icon at the left side of the "a" element, something just like an open book. (I have no privileges to upload image)

What is the meaning of the icon? Is there anything that Dreamweaver implies? I've tried to google some groups of keywords, and got nothing but ads.

Any help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there this "test" id will be used by another element?

Comment: No, every id is unique in this page. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This icon (should look like a shield with an anchor on it) is a Dreamweaver design view indicator. This indicator is used to identify "named" anchors. No image that will be uploaded to your site, so don't worry about that. Anchor () tags with an ID are considered "named" as you can add a hash to the end of your URL to have the browser "jump" to the named/ided element. If you file is test.html and you visit your page with test.html#test  then the browser will load up your page and "jump" to the named anchor. In recent browsers (not sure how far back, but likely far enough to not worry too much about it now) anchors with an id attribute value will work in the same manner as those with a name attribute value.

If you do not like this icon appearing when you have a couple of options:
Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) -> Preferences, Invisible Elements, uncheck Named anchors.

Or View -> Visual Aids -> Invisible Elements. This option turns off all invisible element indicators listed in the preferences, so make sure you know what things your turning off.

Comment: Yeah, it does look like a shield but not a book :). Your answer is quite clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just using the symbol to identify text on the page that's a link, save the file and load it up in your web browser, chances are the icon isn't actually part of your code.